# Netty 4 not work in more than 4 channels

Tags: java, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, netty

i have some netty-server which i use for uploading files on amazon s3.i try do some test with jmeter and i get strange trouble: my server get just 4-files and start uploading them. other files handle after one of those 4files complete uploading. i thing that netty must work with many threads, not 4.sorry for my english, i need help and hope for your advices.
there is my handler

```
 protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, HttpObject msg) throws Exception {

    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        System.out.println("request");
        request = (HttpRequest) msg;
        reqURI = request.getUri();
        QueryStringDecoder queryStringDecoder = new QueryStringDecoder(reqURI);
        switch (queryStringDecoder.path()) {
            case ("/getfile"):
                sendSimpleResponse(channelHandlerContext, OK, "getfile");
                break;
            case ("/upload"):
                showUploadForm(channelHandlerContext);
                break;
            case ("/formpostmultipart"):
                if (request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.POST)) {
                    decoder = new HttpPostRequestDecoder(dataFactory, request);
                    decoder.setDiscardThreshold(0);
                } else {
                    sendSimpleResponse(channelHandlerContext, BAD_REQUEST, "");
                }
                break;
            default:
                sendSimpleResponse(channelHandlerContext, NOT_FOUND, "");

        }
    }

    if (decoder != null) {
        if (msg instanceof HttpContent) {
            HttpContent chunk = (HttpContent) msg;
            decoder.offer(chunk);
            readChunk(channelHandlerContext);
            if (chunk instanceof LastHttpContent) {
                resetPostRequestDecoder();
            }
        }
    }
}
private void readChunk(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws IOException {
    while (decoder.hasNext()) {
        InterfaceHttpData data = decoder.next();
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                switch (data.getHttpDataType()) {
                    case Attribute:
                        break;
                    case FileUpload:
                        FileUpload fileUpload = (FileUpload) data;
                        System.out.println("send file call");
                        logger.info("start upload");
                        AWSfunctions aws = new AWSfunctions();
                        aws.sendFile(fileUpload);
                        break;
                }
            } finally {
                data.release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this class for work with amasons3. (you can see that i try give more connections for client,but this not work too)

```
public class AWSfunctions {
AmazonS3 connection;

AWSfunctions() {
    Config conf;
    String AccessKeyId;
    String SecretKey;
    AWSCredentials credentials;
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration;
    conf = ConfigFactory.load();
    AccessKeyId = conf.getString("AWSCredentials.AWSAccessKeyId");
    SecretKey = conf.getString("AWSCredentials.AWSSecretKey");
    credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKeyId, SecretKey);
    clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    clientConfiguration.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
    clientConfiguration.setMaxConnections(200);
    System.out.println(clientConfiguration.getMaxConnections());
    connection = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, clientConfiguration);
}

public void sendFile(FileUpload fileUpload) throws IOException {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    File file;
    file = fileUpload.getFile();
    System.out.println("upload started");
    connection.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("test-for-est", String.valueOf(rnd.nextInt()), file));
    System.out.println("Upload completed");
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, it very simple. i did some change in server class...

```
public void run() throws Exception {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ServerInitializer());
        ChannelFuture ch = b.bind(port).sync();
        ch.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

change

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
```

to

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(20);
```